I am trying to setup a new tag in GTM which should get triggered when images are scrolled/swapped on a product page on mobile for e-commerce website
I am trying to setup a new tag in GTM which should get triggered when images are scrolled/swapped on a product page on mobile for an e-commerce website.
Trigger setting I selected:
enter image description here
Tag setting I selected:
enter image description here
I am checking in GA4, but this Tag is not triggering when I am scrolling images on mobile on product page.
please help me out with this.
Trigger setting I selected:
enter image description here
Tag setting I selected:
enter image description here
I am checking in GA4, but this Tag is not triggering when I am scrolling images on mobile on product page.
please help me out with this.

Yes, it's working, but not how I was expecting. Basically, I want to create a Google Tag for my GA4 so that it is triggered only when an image is scrolled/swapped on the product page(on mobiles). But I can't find any specific class on my website's product page to use in Element Selector that I can use to achieve this.
For example a product has two images, first image will load with the page loaded, and to see the second image on mobile screen, we have to scroll/swap the first image towards left to see the second image.
my demo website: https://justonesale.myshopify.com, use password: 5

For CSS Selector
If there are multiple classes in one html dom like a div

Your selector can not be
.site-overview-wrap sidebar-panel sidebar-panel-active
The correct one is
.site-overview-wrap.sidebar-panel.sidebar-panel-active
Every class should start with "."

Here is a tip you can quick test the CSS selector with your Chrome Dev Tool.
Go to the Console tab.
Use the snippet
$$(".site-overview-wrap.sidebar-panel.sidebar-panel-active")
If the result has something rather than empty. The css selector could be the right one.


Here is the overview for the product page
If you want when the user scroll and see the 3rd image or 2nd image
I will suggest use the Element Visibility Trigger with the following CSS Selector
2nd image:
ul.product__media-list li:nth-child(2).product__media-item img
3rd image:
ul.product__media-list li:nth-child(3).product__media-item img



Yes, it's working, but not how I was expecting. Basically, I want to create a Google Tag for my GA4 so that it is triggered only when an image is scrolled/swapped on the product page(on mobiles). But I can't find any specific class on my website's product page to use in Element Selector that I can use to achieve this.
For example a product has two images, first image will load with the page loaded, and to see the second image on mobile screen, we have to scroll/swap the first image towards left to see the second image.
my demo website: https://justonesale.myshopify.com, use password: 5
